# to use mysql server as a client of ldap

Tags: mysql

Does opensource version of MySql support authentication using ldap & pam ? I need to use my ldap server for central authetication of all my database servers. ( Not the OS but MySql server ) OS is already configured for central auth but mysql is not working. I tried to do it via /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/authentication_pam.so but seems its not present in default installation.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Server Fault, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, PAM auth plugin is available in the Enterprise/Commercial version of Oracle Mysql.
You might try the Percona provided [plugin](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-pam-for-mysql/)